# Can a MonoBehaviour be a private inner class?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to use a private inner class `MonoBehaviour` as part of the internal implementation of a class (also a `MonoBehaviour`). Reduced to the essentials:

```
public class OuterClass : MonoBehaviour {
  public void SomeMethod(GameObject go) {
    go.AddComponent<InnerClass>();
  }

  private class InnerClass : MonoBehaviour {
  }
}
```

**This appears to be all working absolutely fine, with no errors or warnings.** But it also appears to violate the statement in the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html) that:

> The class name and file name must be the same to enable the script
> component to be attached to a GameObject.

Is this a problematic violation of that rule? If so, what are the problems? I am aware that it means the script is not visible in the Editor, but that's exactly what I want: it should never be added by anything other than its enclosing class.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66807151/can-a-monobehaviour-be-a-private-inner-class). Cross-posting on StackExchange sites is not allowed. Please select the site where you think you'll get the most/best answers and post only there. If it's gamedev, then please delete the on on SO and flag for moderators here so we can reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that it means the script is not visible in the Editor

That is the consequence that the Unity documentation is warning you about.

> but that's exactly what I want: it should never be added by anything other than its enclosing class.

> This appears to be all working absolutely fine, with no errors or warnings

Then it sounds like you've considered and tested the possible pros and cons of this approach and concluded that it serves your needs.